# Can't iterate over set() properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using python to create an empty set(), every keystroke i press adds to that set, which works very well!

But when i for example press "s" and try to iterate over the set, it always returns false. What am i doing wrong? Thanks!

```
from pynput import keyboard

pressed = set()

def on_press(key):
    pressed.add(key)
    # THIS RETURNS FALSE EVERYTIME!!! ???
    print('s' in pressed)


def on_release(key):
    if key in pressed:
        pressed.remove(key)


with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: try adding some debugging statements to your code, e.g., `print(f'pressed {key}')` at the top of `on_press`.

Comment: @TomKarzes If you run my code and press the keystroke "s" it should return true, but it returns false everytime. Pressing "s" adds the key to the "pressed" set, and when i iterate over it with this line of code "print('s' in pressed)" it returns false.

Comment: Are you sure that `key` is `'s'`…?

Comment: @AndrewJaffe I tried it and i get the print 's' when i press it, so it should work?

Comment: @deceze If i print the "pressed" set, i get this "{'s'}", so it contains the s, but i just cant seem to iterate over it with a true answer, idk what i am doing wrong.

Comment: @TomKarzes Could you please explain what this means? I thought I should be able to iterate over a Set()?

Comment: @TomKarzes: So, doesn't `'s' in pressed` count as iteration? Might the `set` be iterating to find the key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object you are adding to the set is *not* the string `s` but instead a `'pynput.keyboard._xorg.KeyCode'` class instance. So your `in` test will fail as these items are not equal.

To get the key's character, you need to do:

```
pressed.add(key.char)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are just storing instances of `pynput.keyboard.<platform>.KeyCode`. You meant to do this:

```py
def on_press(key):
    pressed.add(key.char)
    print('s' in pressed)
```